# Can I create multiple constructors with the same arguments

Tags: c++, class, constructor, overloading

Im new to C++ and I am curious to know if you can create multiple constructors with the same arguments. Say for example I have this class in which I have patients and I have their name and their age.  I know I can create a constructor like  this:

```
class hospital {
  hospital(){
    setname("John");
    setage(24);
  }
private:
  string name;
  int age;
};
```

but could I create another constructor just like I did above. Something like:

```
hospital patientBilly(){
  setname("Billy");
  setage(32);
}
```

Comment: How to know which constructor to call?

Comment: You do that by providing the constructor with the name and age as arguments. Do you plan on creating one constructor for every conceivable combination of name and age that could ever exist? (And that type should probably be called "patient", not "hospital".)

Comment: `hospital patientBilly()` is **not** a constructor, it's a member function, you can only call it on already existing object. Constructors don't have an explicit return type, as their name is the same as the class name.

Comment: @Kaldrr: It's not unheard of to have a `static hospital patientBilly()` method. It's sometimes called a "named constructor pattern".

Comment: btw name `hospital` is strange for something which seems to be a `Person`.

Comment: The question asked and the accepted answer are very different. Maybe it is what the OP wanted, but not what they asked.

Comment: @Maaz what I was asking was if I could essentially do something like ` class hospital {
  hospital(){
    setname("John");
    setage(24);
  }
private:
  string name;
  int age;
}; `                                                                                                                                and just add constructors with different info but you cant do this its impossible so for what I need the answer I took was great it lets me store objects in a vector which is great for my use but I believe my question was answered for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your problem you have two concepts, which you are trying to mix.
hospitals and patients. So it makes sense to model them as two distinct classes.

This way you can model a patient as something that has an age and a name.
And a hospital as something that "contains" patients.

Give the patient a contructor where you can pass age and name.
And give the hospital a method or methods to add patients.
In the example I show to variants of how you could add patients to a hospital.

I also have use unsigned variable types for numbers that can never be smaller then 0. And I use the const keyword a lot for places in the code where values must only be used, and should not be changed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>


//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class patient_t
{
public:

    // You need a constructor like this
    patient_t(const unsigned int age, const std::string& name ) :
        m_age{ age },
        m_name{ name }
    {
    }

    // getter function for observing private data
    const unsigned int& age() const noexcept
    {
        return m_age;
    }

    // getter function for observing private data
    const std::string& name() const noexcept
    {
        return m_name;
    }

private:
    unsigned int m_age;
    std::string m_name;
};

// a useful output function to have (will make code later shorter)
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const patient_t& patient)
{
    os << "Patient : " << patient.name() << ", age : " << patient.age() << std::endl;
    return os;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class hospital_t
{
public:
    void add_patient(const unsigned int age, const std::string& name)
    {
        m_patients.emplace_back(age,name); // will call patient constructor with two parameters age and name and puts it into vector
    }

    void add_patient(const patient_t& patient)
    {
        m_patients.push_back(patient); // store a copy of patient in the vector
    }

    const auto& patients() const
    {
        return m_patients;
    }

private:
    std::vector<patient_t> m_patients;
};

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
    hospital_t hospital;
    patient_t  billy{ 42, "Billy" };
    hospital.add_patient(billy);
    hospital.add_patient(31, "Jane");

    for (const auto& patient : hospital.patients())
    {
        std::cout << patient;
    }
}
```

Comment: AWSOME this is perfect

Comment: Small fix to operator<< , I streamed to std::cout instead of os.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you redefine the constructor. Allowed is only one definition.
Simplified example:

```cpp
void myFunc (){};

void myFunc (){};

int
main ()
{
  myFunc ();
}
```

I whould make the Hospital class like this:

```cpp
#include <string>
struct Hospital // struct here to signal we have no invariant. you could also use a class and make the member public
{
  std::string name{}; // no setter and getter if you do not have invariant.
  int age{};
};

int
main ()
{
  auto hospital = Hospital{ .name = "John", .age = 42 }; //c++20 Designated Initializers so we can construct Hospital with a name and age without defining a constructor
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are currently only a bit confused. So lets become the things sorted...

A class describes how objects should behave. The constructor is part of that description and equal to all the instances it will later on create. Your first step for understanding should be: There is a single class and multiple instances/objects of it.

So you write a single class and give for each of the instances/objects different parameters to get different objects.

Example:

```
class hospital {
    public:
    hospital(const std::string& name_, int age_ ):
        name { name_ }, age{ age_ }{
        }

    void Print() const
    {   
        std::cout << "Hospital" << name << ":" << age << std::endl;
    }   

    private:
    std::string name;
    int age;
};

int main()
{
    hospital hospital1{ "John", 24 };
    hospital hospital2{ "Bill", 77 };

    hospital1.Print();
    hospital2.Print();
}
```

You *can* also create a different class for every of your later created objects, but I believe that is never what you want to do, especially not at the beginning of your C++ career!

If you want to create some kind of list of instances, you can store the objects in containers and act on the containers as you like.

```
int main()
{
    std::vector< hospital > objs;

    objs.emplace_back( "John", 24 );
    objs.emplace_back( "Bill", 77 );

    for ( const auto& hos: objs )
    {   
        hos.Print();
    }   
}
```

Comment: I understand I can do this but I dont want to have to call them in main every time.  I am trying to implement something where when I print I print the entire roster of people so here when you call print you only call one person when I would like to call print I would like to call everyone at once.  So when I print hospital2 I want it to also print everyone before that like everyone in hospital1 and so on.

Comment: Than you simply have to store your created objects in some kind of container... I will extend my example...

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly then what you need is to define two constructors

```
hospital( const std::string &name, int age )
{
    setname( name );
    setage( age );
}

hospital() : hospital( "John", 24 )
{
}
```

Then you will can write declaring an object of the class

```
hospital patientBilly( "Billy", 32 );
```

Comment: Ok I think I understand you use a constructor for a constructor right?

Comment: No I dont want to declare multiple objects

Comment: @ConnerSmith You need to define an object of the class with specified name and age. So you need a corresponding constructor that accepts two arguments.